# Build a context-free grammar for the language

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

Build a context-free grammar for the language:

> $L=\{\#x\#y\#\,\,;\,\,|x|=|y|\,\,\wedge\,\,x,y\in\{0,1\}^{*}\}$ over $\sum=\{0,1,\#\}$

How can I make sure that |x|=|y|?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercise-like tasks for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: Let me direct you towards our 
[reference questions](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/599)
which cover your problem in detail, particularly https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18524/755.
Please work through the related questions listed there, try to solve your 
problem again and edit to include your attempts along with the specific 
problems you encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without giving you all the answer, consider using the following rules (to be completed):

> $X \to AXA$
>
> $A \to 0 \mid 1$